# Create multiple fields as arrays in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with multiple columns as such:

```
| ID | Grouping | Field_1 | Field_2 | Field_3 | Field_4 |
|----|----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | AA       | A       | B       | C       | M       |
| 2  | AA       | D       | E       | F       | N       |
```

I want to create 2 new columns and store an list of of existing columns in new fields with the use of a group by on an existing field. Such that my new dataframe would look like this:

```
| ID | Grouping | Group_by_list1 | Group_by_list2 |
|----|----------|----------------|----------------|
| 1  | AA       | [A,B,C,M]      | [D,E,F,N]      |
```

Does Pyspark have a way of handling this kind of wrangling with a dataframe to create this kind of an expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added inline comments, Check below code.

```
df \ 
.select(F.col("id"),F.col("Grouping"),F.array(F.col("Field_1"),F.col("Field_2"),F.col("Field_3"),F.col("Field_4")).as("grouping_list"))\ # Creating array of required columns.
.groupBy(F.col("Grouping"))\  # Grouping based on Grouping column.
.agg(F.first(F.col("id")).alias("id"),F.first(F.col("grouping_list")).alias("Group_by_list1"),F.last(F.col("grouping_list")).alias("Group_by_list2"))\ # first value from id, first value from grouping_list list, last value from grouping_list
.select("id","Grouping","Group_by_list1","Group_by_list2")\ # selecting all columns.
.show(false)

+---+--------+--------------+--------------+
|id |Grouping|Group_by_list1|Group_by_list2|
+---+--------+--------------+--------------+
|1  |AA      |[A, B, C, M]  |[D, E, F, N]  |
+---+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Note:**  This solution will give correct result only if `DataFrame` has two rows.

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, what if there are more rows?

Comment: If you have more rows, you may need to change logic inside .agg function..think how many rows you will be converting to columns..